# memory allocation of char arrays in different contexts

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Let's say I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int number1;  /* dummy */
    int number2;  /* dummy */
    int number3;  /* dummy */
    char *name1;
    char name2[];
} Klass;
```

and the rest of the code is:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *name1 = "this is a name";            /* 1st case */
    char name2[] = "this is also a name";      /* 2nd case */

    Klass k;
    k.number1 = 10;
    k.number2 = 20;
    k.number3 = 30;
    k.name1 = "this is my first name";         /* 3rd case */

    /* error: invalid use of flexible array member */
    k.name2 = "this is my second name";

    Klass *kp = (Klass*)malloc(sizeof(Klass));
    kp->number1 = 100;
    kp->number2 = 200;
    kp->number3 = 300;
    kp->name1 = "this is also my first name";  /* 4th case */

    /* error: invalid use of flexible array member */
    kp->name2 = "this is my second name";

    return 0;
}
```

1. Can anyone clarify for me how the memory is allocated (heap vs stack) in the marked cases?
2. How should I free memory at the end of main block?
3. What's the reason compiler is giving the `error: invalid use of flexible array member`?

**EDIT**
If you  say `k.name = "this is my name";` and `kp->name = "this is also my name";` is on the stack, can you explain how I can reach `"this is my name"` like this:

```
Klass *kp;

int foo() {
    Klass k;
    k.number1 = 10;
    k.number2 = 20;
    k.number3 = 30;
    k.name = "this is my name";
    kp = &k;
} // k is destroyed now

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    kp = (Klass*)malloc(sizeof(Klass));
    foo();
    printf("%d\n", kp->number1); /* segfault */
    printf("%d\n", kp->number2); /* segfault */
    printf("%d\n", kp->number3); /* segfault */
    printf("%s\n", kp->name);    /* prints "this is my name" */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One question at a time please. You've got three different things in there, the first two of which have been asked & answered numerous times already.

Comment: The reason for 3. is that you cannot assign to arrays. That it's a flexible array member is incidental.

Comment: @Mat I would love to see links to those questions so that I can explain why those answers do not work for me..

Comment: the answer to ur second question is you only need to free kp, since that is the only one you've allocated on heap. the answer to your third question is that you can't assign to an array. Also the array in question is an flexible array. for more information about it, check out this [post](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEMxx-C.+Understand+how+flexible+array+members+are+to+be+used)

Comment: @BeyondSora it seems like a good source, unfortunately code snippets do not load for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *name1 = "this is a name";            /* 1st case */
```

This just allocates a pointer, setting it to point to the string (which is kept as static data).

```
char name2[] = "this is also a name";      /* 2nd case */
```

This is short for `char name2[sizeof(init_string)] = "this is also a name";` and allocates enough space to store the characters in the string.

Your third case

```
char name2[];
```

allocates no space at all! There is nowhere to store a string (which would have had to be copied using `strcpy` anyway).

The 4th case

```
kp->name1 = "this is also my first name";  /* 4th case */
```

is similar to case 1 - `name1` is a pointer that is set to point to a static text.

Comment: what about memory management with that 'static data', is it on the heap or stack? am I supposed to free it afterwards?

Comment: No, static data is a separate area (not stack and not heap). You don't have to do anything, it's handled by the system.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays of flexible length are meant to be used mostly with pointers.

```
Klass *kp = malloc( sizeof(Klass) + 100 );
```

This 100 are extra bytes that can be accessed via a `name2` member. Usually there is a member of the structure used for storing a flexible part size.

Freeing this memory isn't any different from the one you would use for a regular structure.

The reason why compiler complains is that it's still an array (not a pointer) and you can't simply assign arrays. When you are accessing `kp->name2` no additional indirection is introduced (unlike in the case when `name2` is a pointer).

As for memory allocation:

1) `name1` is a pointer to some memory region (most likely read-only memory) where a string literal is stored (bytes that comprise a char array with terminating 0). Trying to modify a string that `name1` points at will result in an undefined behavior (you are not allowed to modify string literals).

2) `name2` is an array and it's on the stack. You can freely modify its contents. The initialization code that puts a string literal to this array might be different among different platforms and compilers. I have even seen a disassembly, where a string literal is in read-only memory region (.rodata) and it's simply `memcpy`'ed to `name2.

3) and 4) are the attempts to assign to arrays which is illegal.

Comment: I think you have mixed the case indexes in your answer but I guess it's because my question is confusing with all those question/case/variable indexes. I think I have got your answer anyway, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

1. 1. The memory for the string is in a static region, which is where all string constants live. `name1` is just a pointer to that region.
   2. The memory has automatic storage ("on the stack").
   3. Same as in case 1.
2. Yes, since you've called `malloc`. Every `malloc` must be mirrored by a call to `free`.
3. In `Klass`, the member `name2` is a [flexible array member](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/flexible-array-member/), whose size is unknown to the compiler (and for which, btw., you haven't allocated any memory in the `malloc` call). Also, you can't directly copy arrays in C; had you allocated enough memory, you could use `memcpy` or `strcpy`.

Comment: your answer is missing 1.4 but I'm guessing it's also 'same as in case 1'

Comment: @gokcehan: hadn't seen it, but it's indeed the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only moment when you should free the memory yourself is when you come to (m)alloc something, or call a function which do so (`strdup()`, ...)

In case 1,3 and 4 you are allocation the string on the stack, those string won't be available when you go out of your function. The 2nd case is a bit tricky, but this string is hardcoded in the executable, and you can not modify it (You would have a segmentation fault if you try to do so).

You can not make name2 poiting to a string, as name2 is not a pointer, but an array.

Comment: Because you are using an hardcoded string, the string is mapped in memory. But what is happening is an undefined behavior anyways. It could segfault anytime.